# Some problems about symmetric convolution semigroup on the unit circle

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, stochastic-processes

These are problems from Example 1.4.2 of Fukushima's book "Dirichlet forms and symmetric Markov processes".

Let $\Lambda$ be the set of all real sequences $\left\{\lambda_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ satisfying
$$\lambda_0=0, \lambda_n=\lambda_{-n}\text{ for all }n\in\mathbf{Z},$$
and
$$\sum_{m,n\in\mathbf{Z}}(\lambda_n+\lambda_m-\lambda_{n-m})\rho_n\rho_m\ge0,$$
where $\left\{\rho_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ is any sequence of real numbers with only finite elements non-vanishing.

1. The authors claim that if $\left\{\lambda_n\right\}$ satisfies the first condition and $\lambda_n$ is concave and increasing for $n>0$, then it satisfies the second condition.
2. The authors claim that if $\left\{\lambda_n\right\}\in\Lambda$, then for all $t>0$
   $$\sum_{m,n\in\mathbf{Z}}\exp[t(\lambda_n+\lambda_m-\lambda_{n-m})]\rho_n\rho_m\ge0,$$
   where $\left\{\rho_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ is any sequence of real numbers with only finite elements non-vanishing.

I do not know how to prove these two results. Could someone give some hints?

Comment: 2) follows from 1). Indeed, pointwise product of positive semidefinite matrices $A,B$ is again p.d., hence so are $A^k$ for $k\geq 0$ and $e^{tA}$ for $t>0$.

Comment: For proving 1), it suffices to consider $\lambda_n=\min(|n|,M)$ for fixed positive integer $M$. Any other concave increasing sequence is a positive linear combination of such sequences.

Comment: But how to prove this case?